# text and texture not visible in output video

Tags: texturing, uv, export, video, text-editor

I have created an animated text intro from a blender tutorial but when I try to export it to a video, it only exports the effects I created in "compositing" and not the entire animation with the text and textures added. I have tried everything save it all together so it will export together but nothing is working. I know there has to be a simple fix. Any help would be high appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site. You will make it easier for others on the site to help you if you: 1) edit your question to give more detail, of what your project is not doing that you want it to, and 2) upload a copy of your ~.blend file to [Blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) or another, similar site of you own choosing, and link to the file in your question.

Comment: If you only get your compositing effects then you may not have the original render result mixed into the final image. Add a screenshot of your compositing nodes.

Comment: I figured it out. my initial node was still in alpha and not image. I've been trying to figure this out for 2 day. simple  mistakes smh. thank you for responding.

Comment: You should "answer" your question with the solution ;-)